# Auto sync with a github repo

Tags: github

Is there anyway I can set my machine to automatically pull down the repo every time the repo in github is committed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) entry for that. Working with commit hooks triggered from GitHub requires your host being reachable directly from the internet.

Fast forward pulls into your checked out repository only works if you don't change or commit anything locally. Otherwise you have to reset changes.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for syncing documents, try [Sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org).